# EEA Family Permit - Application form family details

Tags: united-kingdom, eu-citizens, eu-spouses

[image: EEA family permit application screen]

I'm a non-EU-citizen currently living in Lithuania while my Lithuanian wife has been living and working in the UK for 2 months already.

My question is, in *Family Details*, do I have to give my parents' information or that of my wife's parents?

Comment: Please *type* the relevant parts of the question into the text - pictures are not searchable ([we don't like that on SE sites](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)).

Comment: What nationalities does your wife have?  (Or, rather more to the point, does she have any EEA nationalities like Lithuanian.)

Comment: @JanDoggen If the OP can manage to construct a text version of the form with HTML tags (the notes are needed, as well as the questions), that would be brilliant.  Realistically though, I think in this case a screen shot is acceptable.

Comment: @MartinBonner she presumably does have an EEA nationality, since otherwise Zyzz would not be applying for an EEA family permit.

Comment: @phoog The OP might be *incorrectly* applying for an EEA family permit; that's what I wanted to check.

Comment: @MartinBonner ah yes, of course.

Comment: @MartinBonner My wife is Lithuanian.

Comment: @MartinBonner 3 persons I know had to get the EEA family permit. But 4 years ago it was sufficient to go just with your wife together through the border. But this does not work anymore because it causes more delay while they're undee investigation. So EEA family permit is good but confusing to fill.

Comment: @Zyzz I have edited your question to add the information that your wife is Lithuanian.  Questions should be standalone (comments are ephemeral).  Please either approve the edit, or reject it and add the information yourself.

Answer (score 1):

It's asking for your parents' details.  Information related to your wife will be covered in the later section called "EEA National."

Comment: I was about to say "What an appallingly designed form. It's asking for your wife's details."  At least the first sentence is true.

Comment: @MartinBonner that is certainly true.  The main reason for asking about parents as far as I can tell is to aid in establishing the applicant's identity.  There's certainly no reason to ask about them for determining whether the applicant is eligible for the permit.  There's also no need to establish the EEA principal's identity with such precision.  That also tends to support this conclusion.  But the appalling design is such that when I filled it out for my mother-in-law, with my wife as the principal, it asked when they first met and whether they had any children together.  It's truly awful.

Comment: My wife is EEA national. And I believe 4 years ago it was not required to get EEA family permit. But now it is.

Comment: @Zyzz the EEA family permit is not, strictly speaking, required, because the law provides that someone who arrives at the border and asserts free movement rights must be given an opportunity to make his or her case there at the border.  However, the permit *is* effectively required for anyone who is flying to the UK with a passport that is not visa exempt, because airlines are required to ensure that their passengers have proper documents.  None of this has changed in the last several years.

Comment: @Zyzz I just noticed your comment on the question itself about delay caused by investigation when asserting free movement rights at the border.  That does not surprise me, and I expect it may indeed have gotten worse over the last few years.